# How to mock external dependencies using JustMock Lite

Tags: c#, unit-testing, justmock

I am using free version of JustMock to mock some external dependencies like [GetUserSettingsResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.autodiscover.getusersettingsresponse(v=exchg.80).aspx) which is a sealed class. The problem is that the free version does not allow us to mock sealed classes. I cannot use the full version because of some reasons. Below is my code sample:

```
public GetUserSettingsResponse GetUserSettingsResponse(string emailAddress)
{
    var response = service.GetUserSettings(
        emailAddress,
        UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl,
        UserSettingName.InternalEwsUrl,
        UserSettingName.EwsSupportedSchemas);
        return response;
}
```

This is the method I am trying to mock as below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetExchangeService()
{
    //Arrange            
    string url = "";
    GetUserSettingsResponse response;
    ObjectOfMyClass.Arrange(x => x.GetUserSettingsResponse(Arg.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new GetUserSettingsResponse()); //this is where it throws exception saying that only non-sealed classes can be mocked with lite version of just mock

}
```

**Edit:** My application is a Web service which is basically using EWS managed APIs to get the email account details from the exchange server. So, in order to start the communication I am first doing the AutoDiscovery to get the url out of email address of the user. So the subject under test is below method which internally calls GetUserSettingsResponse method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ExchangeService GetExchangeService(
                string userName,
                string password,
                int version,
                string emailAddress,
                string userId)
    {
        AutoDiscoverService service = new AutodiscoverService();
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        service.EnableScpLookup = true;

        service.ReturnClientRequestId = true;

        service.PreAuthenticate = false;

        service.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = RedirectionUrlValidationCallback;

        var url = string.Empty;
        var response = GetUserSettingsResponse(emailAddress);
        if (response.TryGetSettingValue(UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl, out settingValue)
            || response.TryGetSettingValue(UserSettingName.InternalEwsUrl, out settingValue))
        {
            ewsurl = settingValue;
        }
        var exchangeService = new ExchangeService((ExchangeVersion)version)
                                      {
                                          Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password),
                                          KeepAlive = true,
                                          Url = new Uri(ewsurl)
                                      };
        return exchangeService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coupling to implementation concerns make it difficult to replace them when trying to test in isolation. Abstract implementation concerns behind interface and abstraction that you have control over. That way you are not confined to the limitations imposed by 3rd party dependencies. This should be an indicator that some solid refactoring is in order to make your code clean.

Comment: How do I separate the implementation and write an interface in this scenario? It would be great if you can throw some examples.

Comment: You need to provide more context information about the subject under test. based on the current code I can only guess it has something to do with exchange.

Comment: @Nkosi I have edited my post with more info.

Comment: Now to clarify, are you trying to hit the actual service or are you trying to test that method in isolation? 'cause that would change this from a unit test to an integration test. A whole new topic

Comment: No, I am not trying to hit the actual service (autodiscovery). Thats why I am trying to Arrange GetUserSettingsResponse method to return some dummy response.

Comment: Just for reference take a look at this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Code is missing from the SUT

Comment: @Nkosi sorry for the delayed response, I have added the missing return statement from the SUT.

Comment: What edition of visual studio do you use?